# How get latitude and longitude of whole address?

Tags: ios, google-maps, uitextfield, latitude-longitude

I am using Google direction API in which when I enter only name of city then it give the  value of latitude and longitude of source and destination of city address. While I am entering whole addresses like as "B-1,ridhi sidhi complex, Chopra katla,Rani bazar, Bikaner" then I don't give any latitude and longitude. How do I get latitude and longitude of that address from Google direction API?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [loactionTextField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] 
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                       error:nil];
NSArray *array = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
if(array == nil)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    if(array.count > 3)
    {
        lat = [[array objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longt = [[array objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
}
```

I tried your address in this and it does return lat and long.